# Getting the exact layout of jsp page when print button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I have a div in my jsp page which has to be printed. When the print button is clicked everything works fine except the layout design(not able to print the exact style).
After googling I got to know that it is because of the CSS links, which needs to be added explicitly. When I add the same, it seems like my bootstrap link is not working. Can anyone please suggest the best solution for the same.
Following is my code:
Preview of div which needs to be printed:

[image]

Code which executes on click of print button is:

```
function printReceipt(){
         console.log("Printing the receipt");

         var contents = $("#receipt").html();
         var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
         frame1[0].name = "frame1";
         frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
         $("body").append(frame1);
         var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
         frameDoc.document.open();
         //Create a new HTML document.
         frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
         frameDoc.document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />">');
         frameDoc.document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/hmsCss.css" />">');             

         frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');

         //Append the DIV contents.
         frameDoc.document.write(contents);
         frameDoc.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>"><\/script>');
         frameDoc.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"><\/script>');
         frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
         frameDoc.document.close();
         setTimeout(function () {
             window.frames["frame1"].focus();
             window.frames["frame1"].print();
             frame1.remove();
         }, 500);
     }
```

Format of my printed receipt:
[image]

Layout of the header of printed receipt has been altered. How can I make this to work exactly as the preview format. Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="bsmin" />
     ...
<script>
function printReceipt(){
     ...
         frameDoc.document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${bsmin}">');
     ...
}
```

Comment: I have used some styling attributes using bootstrap. Anyway Thank you so much for your answer :-)